# Hbase and Rails to develop a web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hbase

I am having data in the Hbase. Now i need to develop a web application in rails using this data.

can anyone help me on this how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Hbase is a column based DB like cassandra and mongo-db. 
I guess to start with you can use [rhino](https://github.com/sqs/rhino/) and [bigRecord](http://openplaces.github.io/bigrecord/) or [stargate](https://github.com/greglu/hbase-stargate).

Rhino and stargate and maintained but you can get the idea of how to start on this.

Let me know if that helps.